# Xamarin Forms Prism DialogService takes some seconds to show up

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

My Dialog is a simple Frame with an Image, a label to display a question and two more labels (Yes / No) with TapCommand.

I've set up the container with the DialogPage.xaml and DialogPageViewModel and injected in the ViewModel I want to open the dialog.

Here is the code I'm using to call the Dialog:

```
    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        _dialogService.ShowDialog("DiscardPopup", CloseDialogCallback);
    }

    void CloseDialogCallback(IDialogResult dialogResult)
    {            
        var goBack = dialogResult.Parameters.GetValue<bool>("GoBack");

        if (goBack)
            NavigationService.GoBackAsync();
    }
```

If the user taps over the "Yes label", I execute this  command:

```
YesCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => YesTapped());



 private void YesTapped()
 {
      IDialogParameters pa = new DialogParameters();
      pa.Add("GoBack", true);
      RequestClose(pa);
 }
```

If the user taps over the "No label", I simply call:

```
NoCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => RequestClose(null));
```

The "problem" is when the ShowDialog is fired, the DiscardPopup is taking up to 3 seconds to show up.
Is there a way to make it faster?

The same happens with the TapCommands, 2 - 3 seconds when the RequestClose is invoked.

Comment: The dialogs show up very quick. If you're experiencing slow responses I might ask: How large of an image are you using? Is it having to be resized? Are you using an older device? Is your layout overly complex? The DialogService resets the Page's content, so if you have an overly complex page you could potentially have a delay as it re-renders

Comment: Hi @DanS. 
The image of the DialogPage is not large (png file with 10 KB), using Aspect Fill 

I'm using a Galaxy S10 to test

The Page that invokes the Dialog is a bit complex due the quantity of components it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actual code telling you exactly what the issue is, is going to be best guess. Based on your feedback to my comments above I would suggest the following:

- Try displaying the dialog on a test page that doesn't have a complex layout. My guess is that you won't see such a long load time. If that's the case this would point to your layout being overly complex and that the lag time is due to the device struggling to re-render the View
- Try using Prism.Plugin.Popups. You'll need to initialize Rg.Plugins.Popup and register the DialogService. You can see docs on that at http://popups.prismplugins.com

Comment: You are right, if I call the dialog in a fresh page, it works pretty fast.
My Page is currently using an accordion component to add some elements in each category. Probably I'll need to rethink this view.